How to set exception for URL with certain parameters in a string (REACT)
I am trying to conditionally render JSX element  and looking for a way to exclude any URL that has a subpage in it. see example: eg. "/blog/some-parameter"
<div>
{/* Conditionally render the Language switcher */}
{
path == '/blog' || path == "/en/blog" || path == "/blog/any path after this" ? (" ") : (<LanguageSelector />)
}
</div>

